# Vue.js | Crawlers are not able to follow v-for generated links

Tags: laravel, web-crawler, vue.js, google-crawlers

I have a small site which uses Laravel and Vue.js for rendering a list. You can view it [here](https://www.nemaso.de/vergleichen). It looks like the Google crawler cannot follow the links generated by `v-for`.

Google Search Console says: `Not found: vergleichen/%7B%7B%20anbieter.slug%20%7D%7D` and all onpage crawlers I know  are failing crawling the links.

What am  I doing wrong? Is there a workaround? Any help is appreciated ♥

**Update**

@Linus: Your assumption is correct, [this](http://pastebin.com/S285XRwc) is the content of my blade file and the JS looks like this:

```
var suche = new Vue({
   el: '#suchen',
   data: {
        search: ''
     }
});
```

So I have to [create a new component](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) in order to get this working?

**Update**

I switched to [Hideseek](https://github.com/vdw/HideSeek). Problem "solved".

Comment: It seems you created the links like this: `href="{{anbieter.slug}}"`, and the google crawler parses this before Vue replaces it with the actual content. Why, I can only assume that you have that markup directly in thepages HTML, and not in a template? Can you provide code about how your #app is structured?

Comment: Hi Linus, I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

The google crawler parses your HTMl before Vue can replace `{{anbieter.slug}}`

You can extract the content of your `#app` element into a `<template>` element, which google *should* ignore, and set this element as the template for Vue.

This *should* make sure that Vue will first parse the template, insert it into the DOM, and afterwards, the crawler can parse the links.

Untested though.

Example:

```
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#main',
  data() {
    return {
        test: 'Test'
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- nothing here, content will come from the <template> below. -->
</div>
<template id="main">
  {{test}}
</template>
```

To support IE9, use `<script type="x-template">` instead of `<template>`

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/an49og18/

Comment: Ok, I extracted the content of `div#suchen` into `template#suchenTemplate`. I will accept your question asap I can confirm it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed. Enjoy your  weekend ♥

Comment: Update: Suddenly, the search console spitting out some more errors.. So thats not the solution.